# Vscode extension error "Message header must separate key and value using :"

Tags: vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

Vscode extension error: Message header must separate key and value using :

Below image shows the Developer tools console logs.

[image]

I saw this specification of [protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/lsp/3.17/specification/#headerPart)

The question is
this is happening in first request(Initialize request) so my extension stopped working.

My extension was working previously why header formulation is causing issue now?

Any input and suggestion to fix this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case server returned validation message was having CRLF and it was more than 3 lines. So messageBuffer.js was considering message as header.

Fix: Corrected the validation message.

Below code was too harsh so created issue to relax this.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node/issues/1276